# Spring MVC subtract one day

Tags: spring-mvc

I have an input which sends a javascript date object like this:

html

```
<form:input path="ingreso" id="ingreso" value="2015-01-14"/>
```

jQuery

```
$("#ingreso").val( new Date( $(this).val().replace(/-/g,",") ) );
```

On the client side I got:

Wed Jan 14 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (Hora de verano de Argentina)

but on the server side I got:

Tue Jan 13 23:00:00 ART 2015

I'm using Spring MVC. Any ideas?

Comment: One hour* ... I think.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the server date/time isn't set up the same as the browser.

The browser will get the users computers date/time settings but the server will get its own date/time setting, so the two number might not match.

The best way to tackle this problem is always allow the client (browser) to tell the server what time/date it is